# Glide version 4.11.0 is giving "couldn't find compiler.jar" error

Tags: android, gradle, android-glide

We are using glide:4.11.0 in out Android porject. It was working fine till last month. Today when I tried to build our application for kindle device, it is throwing below error.

> Could not find compiler.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/bumptech/glide/compiler/4.11.0/compiler-4.11.0.jar

I did clean build, updated Android Studio to 4.1.1, Invalidated the file Cache. Nothing helped to fix this issue.

Below are the entries in build.gradle file related to glide

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

It was working fine till last month. Can any one please help me to fix this issue.

The only thing I did is updated my mac to Catelina. Android Studio version is 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem. Removing .gradle directory from user home directory fixed the issue.